# can CompletableFuture be worth when assyncronosly writing in a single xml document from different threads

Tags: web-services, concurrency, java-8, completable-future

Scenario: I am coding a soap webservice client and I must transform from the webservice response to our internal xml structure. The answer from user perspective must be faster as possible since it is online process (there is no batch at all involved and can be a considered amount of data according to the search criteria. Please, don't suggest pagination or break in more web calls since it is not part of my question). The webservice answer is quite nested and the outcome from my transformation is a very simple structure with just two levels for each item answered in a list:

```
<myroot>
 <firstelement>some info</firstelement>
 <secondelement>other info</secondelement>
 ...
 <100element>another info</100element>
</myroot>
```

Focus of this question: taking advantage of features added in Java 8 regard concurrency for didactic purposes (by new features I mean https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/changes8.html).

I understand that writing from n threads to the same file demands sincronization. From the sample above I guess it shows how simple will be the writing after the transformation process for each one of the 100 object types answered. The big job lies in process the answer which will contain a lot useless fields for us and other fields that impact how we collect other fields but aren't relevant after filtered applied.

I have been reading a lot for the last weeks looking for some way to take advantange of JAVA 8 features (eg. parallalel stream and completeableFuture) to improve the performance of transforming the web service answer about completeableFuture.thenCombine and must of the examples show a concatenation of string or a simple sum of int values and then, as far as I could judge, they are combined. I start to wondering if I am going to correct direction: having two completeFuture writing in the same place (eg. xml document) assuming it I will gain sincronization behind the scene "by grant".

Comment: I have serious doubts that using any sort of multi-threading will help you here; you want a solution, but you do not even know where the problem is... and to discover that you need to fire up a profiler and understand where your "writing" process spends the majority of time. otherwise this is guessing and it ain't going to do u no good

Comment: @Eugene, in few words, the problem/motivation/goal is "to improve the performance of transforming the web service answer". What is your opinion about: "having two completeFuture writing in the same place (eg. xml document) assuming it I will gain sincronization behind the scene "by grant"", I mean, is there sincronization behind the scene if I have two completeFuture, each one triggering diferent methods that both at the end save in the same xml document?

Comment: What does “writing to the same place” mean? What is a “place”? How do you “write” to it? The `CompletableFuture`s are irrelevant. So are the “different methods”. What matters, is the meaning of “place” and “write” here. But for most possible cases “writing to the same place” can’t work. Either, you synchronize (== no parallel) or you mess up the data.

Comment: @Eugene, For your question: "What does “writing to the same place” mean?" Answer:  writing to a xml document. Based on your comment: "Either, you synchronize or you mess up the data", I am assuming that CompletableFuture there isn't any type of synchonize behind the scene when I write to same output (i.e. xml document). If you can just make it more clear in your answer, which would be the same to answer "NO" to my title question,it is the final answer. Honestly it makes sense when I bring in  mind all examples I have read so far: I didn't see an use of assyncronously saving to same target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CompletableFuture for the sake of writing is only useful for parallel processing. The entire request to reponse should be asyncronous to improve server efficiency (throughput). In your case, it is useful if the generation of the content to be written to XML is bulky and parallel processing improves request time.